# D3 tooltip that is also a a D3 viz

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, tooltip

I really appreciate your help on this - I'm fairly new to D3.

I am working on a sort of nested D3 viz. When one element in the first D3 viz is moused over, I want a second D3 viz (say bar chart distribution of the first's elements) to appear. Is this possible? Could you give me a high level overview of how to implement?

To further illustrate: Let's say first viz is scatter plot of GDP vs. population of various countries. When a particular country on the scatter plot is moused over, I want a bar chart to appear in the tooltip that shows the top 5 industries in that country.

Any help on how to approach this would be much appreciate. Thank you again!

Comment: You just need to render the second visualisation into the container for the tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look into Bootstrap's ["popover"](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage). I like it because is very easy to use. Inside that popover you can insert SVG element and draw your second visualization.

To keep things clean and reusable, I suggest you to read this [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) and write your second chart in reusable manner.